# How to use CircleCI 2.0 Parallelism with Laravel

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

Does anyone have an example `.circleci/config.yml` file a basic PHP Laravel Application that uses CircleCI's parallelism?

I've already split up the dusk tests from the phpunit tests in different `workspaces`, but I'd like to use the `parallelism` feature to get through the `phpunit` tests faster. We have over 200+ tests, and want several instances to test them. Docs are confusing on their site.